# Bringing up the moderator tools on a user's chat profile bumps the page to the top

Tags: bug, chat, moderator-tools

When I hit the "Moderator Tools" button on a chat user's profile, the page jumps to the top if it had been scrolled down, then the dialog with the shiny buttons on it pops up. This is annoying, fix it please?

Chrome 36.0.1985.143 on OS X 10.9.5.